# Android import Apache Commons Math - Unable to use Normal Distribution

Tags: java, android, apache-commons-math

I've imported the Apache Common Math library to use normal distribution. But it isn't working. The error is that it cannot be accessed outside of the package.

I'm unable to import the normalDistributionCDFAlgorithm library.

```
public void calc1()
{
    if (normDist1.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        double mean = Double.parseDouble(meanTxt.toString());
        double standDevi = Double.parseDouble(standDeviTxt.toString());
        double userInput = Double.parseDouble(normDistTxt1.toString());
        double answer;

          NormalDistribution d ;

        if (tglbool1)
        {
            //> greater than
            d = new NormalDistribution(mean,standDevi);
            answer = d.cumulativeProbability(1000);

    }
}
```

Comment: what, exactly, can't be accessed outside the package?

Comment: the import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalCDFAlgorithm. It's red.

Comment: @chiastic-security I don't know if this helps, but the things that aren't working don't have a unlock icon on it. http://imgur.com/a/YI1VS

Comment: @chiastic-security It says it requires a throwable and it is receiving a Math Exception. When i change it there becomes an error with the printStackTrace. Cannot resolve the method.

Comment: Why are you importing that class? You're not using it in your code. You're using `org.apache.commons.math4.distribution.NormalDistribution`.

Comment: It automatically imported.

Comment: Regardless it still says unhandled exeption and then the Math Exception package.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about this library but I suspect you have not added the jar to your project. To do so you should:

1. Place the jar file in the libs folder in the root of your module.
2. Click on File -> Project Settings.
3. On the left side choose the module you want to add the library to
4. On the right side choose tab Dependencies
5. In the bottom press Plus sign and click File dependency
6. Finally choose the corresponding jar and sync the project

*Edit:* Turns out you can also do the following:

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
}
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/YI1VS This may help. The 4 normal distribution algorithms don't have locks on them. They are the only ones.

Comment: @MadWooookie have your tried cleaning and re-compiling your project?

Comment: I have, but now the issue that arrises is that the d.cumulativeProbability(userInput) says unhandled exception org.apache.commons.math.MathException

Comment: @MadWooookie that's an other issue. Please mark as solved then (accept the answer) and create an other thread for that